# How to correctly apply .Find in Word documents from VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, find

I am trying to find in a word document (FromDoc) the string `Appendix A` styled as `Heading 1` using the code below. I developed the code in MS Word VBA Editor and worked very well... until I moved it into Excel VBA.

Since I inserted the code into Excel VBA, I have replaced `.Selection` with `ActiveDocument.Range` as I discovered the former does not work in Excel VBA. However, now the Execute method fails to find `Appendix A`. I have spent many hours troubleshooting including reading StackOverflow's posts, to no avail.

```
' Activate FromDoc
oApp.Visible = True
oApp.ActiveWindow.Activate
FromDoc.Activate

' Find Appendix A

With ActiveDocument
    .Range.WholeStory
    .Range.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    .Range.Find.ClearFormatting

    With .Range.Find
        .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
        .Text = "Appendix A"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
    End With

    .Range.Find.Execute
    .Collapse wdCollapseStart

    Dim r1 As Range
    Set r1 = .Range

End With
```

I am also suspicious about the `Set r1 = .Range`. I am concerned it might not work either.

Grateful for your help in understanding and correcting the issue.

Comment: Everything in Word needs to be scoped to that application if you're controlling it from excel, so `oApp.Activedocument` for example.  However there's no need for that - just use `FromDoc` directly instead of activating it and then using `ActiveDocument`.  Also `Dim r1 As Range` needs to be `Dim r1 As Word.Range` (assuming you've added a reference to Word in your excel vb project) because both Excel and Word have a `Range` type.

Comment: I have replaced `ActiveDocument` with `FromDoc` (except `.Styles` that seems to require `ActiveDocument`) and ran the code, but `.Find.Execute` has failed again... :(

Comment: You haven't showed us how the FromDoc is obtained. Based on the code you posted and your comments above you appear to be unaware that to work with Word documents from Excel you cannot just refer to ActiveDocument.  You MUST precede ActiveDocument with a valid Word Application qualifier.  Likewise.  If you declare a variable as a word range variable then you can't just say range, you would need to qualify the range as Word.Range, otherwise Excel will assume you are asking for an Excel Range.

Comment: Do you have a reference to Word in your excel VB project?

Comment: Yes, it is passed ByRef to this code from another procedure. This is the reference to Word in that procedure:

    `Dim WDApp As Word.Application
    Dim WDDoc As Word.Document
    
    Set WDApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If WDApp Is Nothing Then
        Set WDApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If`

Comment: ...and the reference works, i.e. I can write text in the referenced document (FromDoc) for instance from the immediate window, but, the macro cannot find "Appendix A" that exists in FromDoc and that I can find using the Find window in MS Word! Changing a bit the code results in .Execute to return true, but the range selected is the entire document!! Further to this, I see that the settings for the Find object are affected by the Excel Macro to some extent, but the .Execute method fails. I have restarted the computer etc, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Much of your code serves no useful purpose. For what you've described, Word doesn't need to be visible and you don't need to activate the document; nor do you need to Set a new range. All you need is:

```
With FromDoc
  With .Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Style = "Heading 1"
      .Text = "Appendix A"
      .Format = True
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = 1 'wdFindContinue
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = True
      .Execute
    End With
    With .Duplicate
      .Collapse 1 'wdCollapseStart
      'do whatever it is you want to do before the Appendix A heading.
    End With
  End With
End With
```

Note that I've supplied the numeric values of wdFindContinue and wdCollapseStart; you can't use named constants with late binding (if that's what you're using) unless you first declare them.

Comment: Thank you, Macropod. This is helpful. However, I am still having issues with the `.Execute` method. Please, take a look at my comments above for a description of the issue. Grateful for any help on this.